# SQL Check Constraint that requires a not null value in a column based on the value of another column

Tags: constraint

I have a table with the following two columns

- `OnSite BIT NOT NULL`
- `ClientId INT NULL`

I want to add a constraint that requires `ClientId` to be `NOT NULL` when `OnSite` is true(1).

I could not find anything on the site.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Which DBMS are you using, SQL Server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to enforce the implication:

```
(OnSite=true) => (ClientId is not null)
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
(OnSite=false) or (ClientId is not null)
```

Your constraint therefore becomes:

```
CHECK ( OnSite=0 or ClientId is not null)
```

Comment: Someone posted and then deleted their comment. but I caught it and used it. It is the same logic. Thanks for the help. Check (NOT ([OnSite]=(1) AND [ClientId] IS NULL))

Comment: Yes, the transformation is known as De Morgan's law

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (
    OnSite BIT NOT NULL,
    ClientID INT NULL);

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_ClientId_NotNull CHECK (OnSite=0 OR ClientId IS NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_ClientId_NotNull;
```